# Data e Hora no mesmo campo, como separar no R?

Tags: r

Em uma coluna da tabela, tenho os valores de **DATA** e **HORA** no mesmo campo.

Exemplo:

```
23:02:1989 14:22
```

Preciso separar o **valor de Data e de Hora**.

Como devo fazer?

Obrigado,

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função `strptime()` e outras mais que coloquei no exemplo:

```
x <- "23:02:1989 14:22"
dataHora <-strptime(x, "%d:%m:%Y %H:%M") # converte para o formato adequado
# [1] "1989-02-23 14:22:00 GMT"
```

E se quiser separar em data e em hora:

```
data <- as.Date(dataHora, "%d:%m:%Y")
hora <- format(dataHora, "%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra alternativa é usar o pacote `lubridate`, que faz parte do [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/).

Assim teríamos:

```r
library(lubridate)
x <- "23:02:1989 14:22"
data_hora <- dmy_hm(x)
class(data_hora)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

A função `dmy_hm()` faz o parse de datas que estejam no formato dia, mês, ano, hora e minuto.

A solução oferecida pelo @WillianVieira deixa as horas num formato de texto. Neste caso isso também pode ser feito com manipulação de textos. No [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), isso é feito com o pacote [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr).

```
library(stringr)
separados <- str_split(x, " ")[[1]]
separados[1]
[1] "23:02:1989"
separados[2]
[1] "14:22"
```

Após a separação dos textos é possível fazer o parse da data e da hora separadamente.

```
dt_data <- dmy(separados[1])
class(dt_data)
[1] "Date"
hm_data <- hm(separados[2])
class(hm_data)
[1] "Period"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"
```

Outra alternativa muito usada com o `lubridate`, que tem um tom de gambiarra, é fazer com que todos os elementos de um vetor de data e hora tenham o mesmo dia. Assim as diferenças na parte da hora são lançadas ao primeiro plano.

```
hora <- data_hora + duration(5:14,  "hours")
year(hora) <- 1989
month(hora) <- 1
day(hora) <- 1
hora
 [1] "1989-01-01 19:22:00 UTC" "1989-01-01 20:22:00 UTC"
 [3] "1989-01-01 21:22:00 UTC" "1989-01-01 22:22:00 UTC"
 [5] "1989-01-01 23:22:00 UTC" "1989-01-01 00:22:00 UTC"
 [7] "1989-01-01 01:22:00 UTC" "1989-01-01 02:22:00 UTC"
 [9] "1989-01-01 03:22:00 UTC" "1989-01-01 04:22:00 UTC"
```